# Does the character Aidan exist or was he cut from the game?

Tags: gothic

In the New Camp, Wolf says that I can find Aidan "on the way to the New Camp". Supposedly he can teach me how to skin animals. Wolf also mentions two other characters who are among the first that we meet in the game, and they are much easier to find.

Does Aidan exist or was he cut from the game and is only mentioned by a mistake? If he's out there somewhere, please mark his location on the map.

[image: screenshot of Wolf's dialogue line where he says we can find Aidan on the way to the New Camp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found his hut, it's just on the other side of the scratched up road where a yellow lizard walks around, to the left after crossing the bridge on the path to the New Camp. Here's a screenshot of the map with the arrow looking at Aidan's hut:

[image]

But his dialogue options are empty (only has "END") so I'm guessing I've already learned every skill he can offer to teach me from the other two characters near Old Camp.